# How to define an array with a single `defaults` command?

Tags: plist, defaults

I want a domain `com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0` to contain the following array:

```
(
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 0;
    },
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 2;
    },
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 10;
    }
)
```

I can achieve it by deleting the current value and running three `-array-add` commands:

```
defaults -currentHost delete -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0
defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0 -array-add '{ HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 0; }'    
defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0 -array-add '{ HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 2; }'    
defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0 -array-add '{ HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 10; }'
defaults -currentHost read -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0
```

---

**What syntax can I use to define the array in a single command?**

---

- If I run the following script:

  ```
  defaults -currentHost delete -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0
  defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0 -array '(
    { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 0; },
    { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 2; },
    { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 10; } )' 
  defaults -currentHost read -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0
  ```

  I get an array within an array:

  ```
  (
          (
                  {
              HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2;
              HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 0;
          },
                  {
              HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0;
              HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 2;
          },
                  {
              HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0;
              HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 10;
          }
      )
  )
  ```
- If I try with `-plist` instead of `-array` I get an `Unexpected argument`.
- If I run the following script:

  ```
  defaults -currentHost delete -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0    
  defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0 -array '
    { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 0; },
    { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 2; },
    { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 10; }'
  defaults -currentHost read -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0
  ```

  I get a syntax error `defaults[22044:679428] Could not parse: ... Try single-quoting it.`

---

Question again: what syntax can I use to define the array in a single command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-array` takes individual array elements as individual arguments.

```
defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0 -array \
  '{ HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 0; }' \
  '{ HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 2; }' \
  '{ HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 10; }'
```

The ‘\’ are used to keep the shell waiting for the next line, so they can be omitted if written on one line. You don't need to use `delete` first: unlike `-array-add`, `-array` replaces the entire array with the new contents.

If you don't want to do it this way, here's an alternative: you can pass the data structure as a string. This is closer to the examples in your question and works the same.

```
defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-628-0 '(
  { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 2; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 0; },
  { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 2; },
  { HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 0; HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 10; } )'
```

Comment: This answers my question perfectly. However, shall I ask another question of how to do it with a single argument? My intention was to provide a single data structure, and when writing the question, I did not realise "a single command" and "a single data structure" were requirements that could be fulfilled in different ways.

Comment: @techraf I've edited my answer to include a single-string method, see if that's better

Comment: Oh! Now I get it. `-array` and `-dict` are optional. And I tried to convince it with non-existent `-plist`... Thank you!